# Docker Tomcat Image: Encoding problem with Umlaute when deploying WAR file

Tags: docker, tomcat, gradle, encoding, utf-8

I have a simple (no spring) web application (REST-Service + HTML pages) that is deployed on Tomcat 8.5.

If I put the application sourcecode into a docker container (plain java image FROM java:8-jdk), use gradle to build and run it on an embedded Tomcat that is created with gretty everything works fine.

But when I use a docker image with a preinstalled Tomcat (FROM tomcat:8.5) and deploy the myApp.war (generated by gradle war plugin) the encoding gets messed up and Umlaute like "ü" are shown as "Ã¼".

But that happens only for messages that are shown as a toast with the Javascript lib "toastr" and for subject part of E-Mails I send with "javax.mail.Transport". The content of the html pages and the content auf the mails shows Umlaute as expected.

All files are encoded in UTF-8 (e.g. Java source).
I tried to change the locale on the docker container to de_DE.UTF-8, but that didn't help (it was also already set to en_US.UTF-8 so I guess that wasn't the problem).
I also tried the bitnami-docker-tomcat image which sets "JAVA_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8", but that also didn't help.
And I tried to add an Character Encoding Filter to web.xml. No luck either.

I guess this must be a kind of a common problem, but I couldn't find a working solution.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM tomcat:8.5
ADD app.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

web.xml with Encoding Filter:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>setCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>encoding</param-name>
    <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>setCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I was on the wrong path all along. The problem was neither the docker container, nor the Tomcat configuration. The problem was that the creation of the WAR file went wrong and didn't use UTF-8. Really strange, since gretty should use the same compiled files and produce the same error.

So after adding the following to my gradle build script all Umlauts are finally correctly displayed:

```
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```